# how to add a uniquid to repeater jQuery when click to add row

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a jQuery repeater and input select2 field in it. but in row 2 it doesn't work because the ID the same as first row. I need generate a Id same time as click to add row 
and this is code of the row

```
{{ Form::select('item', $product_services,'', array('class' => 'form-control select2','id'=> 'item','data-url'=>route('invoice.product'),'required'=>'required')) }}



 if ($(selector + " .repeater").length) {
    var $dragAndDrop = $("body .repeater tbody").sortable({
        handle: '.sort-handler'
    });
    var $repeater = $(selector + ' .repeater').repeater({
        initEmpty: false,
        defaultValues: {
            'status': 1
        },
        show: function () {
            $(this).slideDown();
            var file_uploads = $(this).find('input.multi');
            if (file_uploads.length) {
                $(this).find('input.multi').MultiFile({
                    max: 3,
                    accept: 'png|jpg|jpeg',
                    max_size: 2048
                });
            }
            if($('.select2').length) {
                $('.select2').select2();
            }
        },
        hide: function (deleteElement) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
                $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
                $(this).remove();

                var inputs = $(".amount");
                var subTotal = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    subTotal = parseFloat(subTotal) + parseFloat($(inputs[i]).html());
                }
                $('.subTotal').html(subTotal.toFixed(2));
                $('.totalAmount').html(subTotal.toFixed(2));
            }
        },
        ready: function (setIndexes) {

            $dragAndDrop.on('drop', setIndexes);
        },
        isFirstItemUndeletable: true
    });
    var value = $(selector + " .repeater").attr('data-value');
    if (typeof value != 'undefined' && value.length != 0) {
        value = JSON.parse(value);
        $repeater.setList(value);
    }

}
```

it doesn't have some other identifier as you see . thank you

Comment: It's a Laravel for rendering the input once. Show us the code for jQuery which trigger repeater.